# Lightning Input on wrapper class not passing back the value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, wrapper-class, lightning-inputfield

I am using a wrapper class so as not to have a glut of aura:attributes (this may be the problem in and of itself). I have a previous lightning component that has about 16 attributes and passing them all through as method parameters was messing (there is probably a better way of doing that). Here is a more basic example:

WRAPPER CLASS

```
public class CreditAppWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled Credit_Application__c creditApp {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled Business__c business {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled Vehicle__c equipment {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled List<Applicant__c> principals {get;set;}
}
```

COMPONENT

```
 <aura:attribute name="cApp" type="CreditAppWrapper"/>
...
<lightning:input type="String" label="NAME" value ="{!v.cApp.Business.Name}"/>
```

JS CONTROLLER

```
console.log(component.get("v.cApp.Business.Name"));
```

This logs null as the value

Is this because I can't have multiple levels on the input (ie. cApp & Business & Name)? Do I need to instantiate the wrapper class first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm new to lightning, but two things I see:

- The type name in your component isn't matching the class name: 'AppWrapper' versus 'CreditAppWrapper'
- The properties you are exposing aren't primitive types, so yes, they'd need to instantiated.

Comment: Thanks Corey. Yeah, the "AppWrapper" vs "CreditAppWrapper" was a typo when entering it. I figured the instantiating was the issue, but whenever I try to use the default attribute, it breaks a lot of things. Perhpas I will try from my init function.

Comment: Yeah, just instantiating it within my init function did the trick. Thank you, Corey